# How can I change my Desktop Look Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04

[image: Click to see attached picture]

This attached picture shows my required desktop look. I have taken this picture from the website "https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/04/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-18-04" But have no idea how can I change my recent installed Ubuntu 18.04 desktop look to the same as in attached picture.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called "[Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/)" first. Then you'll have to set the position of the panel to "bottom".

[image]
([screenshot source](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/01/dash-to-panel-is-cool-icon-taskbar-for.html))